# Как определить модуль, в котором класс был объявлен непосредственно

Tags: python, классы, numpy, импорт

Для функций Python (если это не builtin) есть отличный лайфхак, позволяющий определить, в каком модуле была объявлена функция:

```
numpy.dot.__globals__['implementation'].__module__
numpy.full.__globals__['__file__']
```

Но данный способ не применим к классам. Для классов предлагаются следующие варианты:

```
inspect.getfile(numpy.dtype)
inspect.getsourcefile(numpy.dtype)
inspect.getmodule(numpy.dtype)
os.path.abspath(sys.modules[numpy.dtype.__module__].__file__)
```

Все эти варианты ведут к файлу `numpy\__init__.py`, но это неправильно. `dtype` объявлен в модуле `numpy.core._multiarray_umath`, а в `numpy\__init__.py` он просто импортируется, и "воспринимается как свой".

Какой функцией воспользоваться, чтобы получить ожидаемый результат, т.е. модуль, где класс "зарождается", а не вставляется из другого модуля?

```
determine_origin(numpy.dtype) # numpy.core._multiarray_umath
```

Answer (score 0):

Я могу ошибаться, но `dtype` - сишная функция. И как результат бессмысленно искать ее через интерфейсы python'a. Почему вы уверены, что `numpy.core._multiarray_umath` модуль, есть ваше искомое? Или у вас есть примеры обратного?

В исходном коде, в `desriptors.c`

```c
/*NUMPY_API
 * Get typenum from an object -- None goes to NPY_DEFAULT_TYPE
 * This function takes a Python object representing a type and converts it
 * to a the correct PyArray_Descr * structure to describe the type.
 *
 * Many objects can be used to represent a data-type which in NumPy is
 * quite a flexible concept.
 *
 * This is the central code that converts Python objects to
 * Type-descriptor objects that are used throughout numpy.
 *
 * Returns a new reference in *at, but the returned should not be
 * modified as it may be one of the canonical immutable objects or
 * a reference to the input obj.
 */
```

То есть приведение типов данных объектов `Python` в объекты `Type-descriptor`, которые используются в numpy.

И как пример, можете глянуть [в эту функцию](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/multiarray/descriptor.c#L1594)

Открытый вопрос: какова ваша конечная цель?

Comment: У меня есть раскомпилированный файл `numpy.core._multiarray_umath` в котором я нахожу и функцию `dot`, и класс `dtype`, и приведённый мною способ для функций (`numpy.dot.__globals__['implementation'].__module__`) выдаёт верный результат (`numpy.core._multiarray_umath`).

И если функция сишная, то можете подсказать способ, как её найти в *.c-модуле?
На открытый вопрос отвечу лично, подскажите, куда могу написать?

Comment: Что за тайны? =) просто если знать и понимать к чему стремиться, то можно найти решение. А так, гадание на кофейной гуще. В любом случае, когда вы работаете с модулями python (не built-in), вы можете сам python запускать с флагом -v (verbose) и импортировать напрямую класс/функцию. На выходе будете иметь все init'ы и import'ы. По ним можно составить дерево зависимостей и анализировать, что откуда прилетает. Конкретно для numpy я бы смотрел в сторону `ctypes` и `_dtype_ctypes` в `numpy.core`. Исходный код на C лежит на github

Comment: ОК, на самом деле ничего тайного. Я пытаюсь получить резюме всей библиотеки: классы, функции. Это мне нужно для изучения библиотек, `numpy` я взял как пример, таким же образом я хочу прорезюмировать другие Python библиотеки. Для изучения мне важно видеть весь модуль, как в таблице Менделеева и отмечать то, что я уже знаю. Но мне не нужно, чтобы функции дублировались из-за импорта и важно видеть, где зарождается каждая функция или класс. Это связано с моим восприятием - я так лучше постигаю информацию